# Posting javascript variable to mysql using ajax in golang

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, go

I find screen size using javascript and want this data to post mysql using ajax. But this is not working. How do I define screen size variable in new.go file? How do I post automatically created screen size information to mysql using ajax?

Here is new.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Call Go</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


            (function (window) {


                    // screen
                    var screenSize = '';
                    if (screen.width) {
                        width = (screen.width) ? screen.width : '';
                        height = (screen.height) ? screen.height : '';
                        screenSize += '' + width + " x " + height;
                    }


                window.jscd = {
                    screen: screenSize,
                };
            }(this));
            alert(
                'Screen Size: ' + jscd.screen
            );


                    $("#callGo").on('click', function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:9000/callme",
                        method: "POST",
                        success: function() {
                            $("#response").html(jscd.screen);
                        },
                    });
                });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="callGo" type="submit">Call Go Code</button>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click callGo named button then response named div success added text must be shown. But how do I do that? How do I connect ajax sending data to go backend code to insert mysql?

Here is my new.go file

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

// Load the index.html template.
var tmpl = template.Must(template.New("tmpl").ParseFiles("new.html"))

func main() {
    // Serve / with the index.html file.
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "new.html", nil); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    })

    // Serve /callme with a text response.
    http.HandleFunc("/callme", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test_db")
        defer db.Close()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        if r.Method == "POST" {
            insForm, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO screen(screen_size) VALUES(?)")
            if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            insForm.Exec(jscd.screen)

        }

        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 301)
    })

    // Start the server at http://localhost:9000
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil))
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `{` in your code after `function (window) {`. Is that just a typo or an error?

Comment: Are you asking how to send information to backend by ajax, using POST method?

Comment: The ajax object has a `data` field, you need to set that to whatever you want to send to the server. The go handler needs to parse the `*http.Request`'s Body, which will contain the contents of the ajax's data field. How to parse the body depends on how the js sent the data (json, form-urlencoded, etc.). After parsing the body content, into a variable you pass that variable, after, of course, validating it, to the sql query.

Comment: Also responding with a 301 redirect will cause, I believe, the ajax's success method *not* to be called. Your Go handler should return 2xx something, most likely 200 (`http.StatusOK`).